# JComboBox Population

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans-8

Hey I am using Netbeans for drag and drop of Graphics Components. You know that there components are automatically initialized, now i am using following function

```
private void idCBAdder() throws SQLException {          //Adds name in Name/Id ComboBox
    sql=new SqlLinking();        
    ArrayList<String> namesList=sql.getNamesList();        
    String[] names= namesList.toArray(new String[namesList.size()]);
    nameCB=new JComboBox(names);
}
```

I got the namesList from the previous class where this function has been Used

```
public ArrayList<String> getNamesList() throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        //Connection establishment
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-CU5U75J\\SQLSERVER1;databaseName=GroceryWithJava", "Fateh", "Fateh");

        //Statement Object
        st = con.createStatement();
        result = st.executeQuery("SELECT Name FROM ProductTB");
        while (result.next()) {
            names.add(result.getString("Name"));
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getCause(),"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return names;
}
```

but after doing this i found my JComboBox without empty whithout any Items there. Actually i am modifying products, adding and deleting so i need it must be updated after each operation that is why i made a method and i want to execute it after each operation.

If i use the following code

```
 private void idCBAdder() throws SQLException {          //Adds name in Name/Id ComboBox
    sql=new SqlLinking();        
    ArrayList<String> namesList=sql.getNamesList();
    for(int i=0;i<namesList.size();i++){
        nameCB.addItem(namesList.get(i));
    }}
```

and i update a product name it duplicates all above products and add one more list of products by increasing it in the JComboBox.

Comment: You're creating a new instance of `JComboBox` each time `idCBAdder` but it's not been added to anything, so it's never been displayed.  Did you mean to update an instance which was already on the screen?

Comment: yeah you got it i wanna update it, Actually i am adding, deleting and updating the names of product so it must also be changed.

Comment: `nameCB.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(names));`

Comment: can u edit my code and tell me where i have to put it. Please.??

Comment: Thanks Very much. I had solved the Problem.

Comment: I would assume replacing `nameCB=new JComboBox(makes);`

Comment: Actually, That worked...!!